# Read decimal from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to read a number of type `decimal(8,2)` from a SQL Server database, and store them in an object, `MyRow`.

```
public class MyRow
{
    public decimal data1 { get; set; }
}

...

List<MyRow> values = new List<MyRow>();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.read())
{
    values.Add( new MyRow() { 
        data1 = decimal.Parse(((double)reader["data1"]).ToString("R")) 
    }
}
```

This solution seems far from ideal, and it seems like I'm doing too much conversion for something that seems like it would be fairly simple. Since the values for `data` are already `decimal(8,2)` in the database, is there any way to read the data into a `decimal` type without the conversion from an `object` to a `decimal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `GetDecimal` method of `SqlDataReader`. A `SqlDataReader` object implmements the `IDataRecord` interface. Hence, it implements many methods. Among these methods, there is the `GetDecimal`.

For further information on this, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getdecimal(v=vs.110).aspx).

That being said, your code can be written as below:

```
List<MyRow> values = new List<MyRow>();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.read())
{
    values.Add(new MyRow() 
    { 
        data1 = reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("data1")) 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [SqlDataReader.GetDecimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlDataReader's [GetDecimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var values = new List<MyRow>();
while (reader.Read())
{
   var r = new MyRow { data1 = reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("data1"))};
   values.Add(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Precision and Scale

Here the code snippet

```
// Assume, com is SqlCommand and ExchangeRate is Parameter

SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@ExChangedRate", SqlDbType.Decimal);
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
parameter.Precision = 16;
parameter.Scale = 2;
com.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```