# C# How do I properly retrieve doubles from a database using a DataAdapter?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ms-access, datagridview, dataadapter

Language: C# DB: Access (So, OleDbDataAdapter)

### Context:

My current project, I'm building a sort of sql query builder. Depending on what the user selects from a drop down list, an sql command can look like this, not sure if it's relevant to the question though [] are columns/table () are drop down optionals, the parenthesis aren't actually there:

```
Select * From [db] where [Date] (between) @value1 and @value2 AND [ID] (=) @ID AND [Usd] (=) @Usd
```

Well, you get the idea.

I run this through the following code:

```
sbuilder = new StringBuilder();

sbuilder.Append("Select * FROM ").Append(Current_Table).Append(" WHERE ");

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Con))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string query = sbuilder.ToString();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();

//some code to build the string, AND build the select parameters, here's the important one though

            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USD", Convert.ToDouble(FilterUSD.Text));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DGVMain.DataSource = dt;
            connection.Close();
        }
```

My problem:

When I retrieve the values, as you expect, they must match the value of FilterUSD.Text, so when a user searches for 12, and the DB contains 12.31251, he will return 0 rows. How do I make it so that when the parameter is 12, it would return all values that have a base value 12 and any following decimal values.  The examples i've looked at online seem to suggeset using an sql data reader, and retrieving the values into a variable Double.

How do I proceed in the context of using a data adapter, as I am currently using, to fill the datatable? (and later, a datagridview)

My hunch is I will have to make use of the parameters of my select command.

Found this link, I dont know how to convert it for my use though as a datatable: [Read decimal from SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185273/read-decimal-from-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your only ever searching for positive whole numbers, so here's two ways which I can think of. I'd probably go with the first one, incase anything unexpected happens with the CAST function.

Add two comparisons in the WHERE clause to pickups records greater than or equal to your search parameter and records less than your search parameter + 1.

```
[Usd] >= 12 AND [Usd] < 13
```

Cast the db field to an int in the WHERE clause, so that the decimal places are removed.

```
cast([Usd] as int) = 12
```

EDIT: Didn't realise you were using Access (above is for SQL Server). This should be used instead: `Int([Usd]) = 12`.

If you want to work with negative numbers as well, then you'll get different results from these 2 options.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to search for negative numbers.

Comment: For a negative numbers, when searching for -12, do you want -12.31251 to appear (show -13 to -12 range) or not appear (show -12 to -11 range)

Comment: To search for positive or negative numbers, use: `Fix([Usd]) = 12`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From [db] where [Date] (between) @value1 and @value2 AND [ID] (=) @ID AND left([Usd],len(Usd)) (=) @Usd
```

the code I added is the left function I'm not aware if this is working with access but I've used this in sql try to give it a shot.  if the DB contains 12.33321 and your parameter name "@Usd" is 12 the db will only give you the whole number you wanted and if -12 but the DB contains -12.3123 it will still give you -12.